# ArrayList.split() method not adding all elements to an array

Tags: arrays, arraylist, input, split, java.util.scanner

```
public static ArrayList<Laptop> readLaptopInputs(Scanner scanner) {
    ArrayList<Laptop> toReturn = new ArrayList<Laptop>();
    System.out.println("Provide information about each laptop, one per line in the format \"Brand, procSpeed, memory, HDD\".");
    while (scanner.hasNextLine() && scanner.next() != "done") {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] info = line.split(", ");
        String brand = info[0];
        double procSpeed = Double.valueOf(info[1]);
        int memory = Integer.valueOf(info[2]);
        int hdd = Integer.valueOf(info[3]);
        Laptop toAdd = new Laptop(brand, procSpeed, memory, hdd);
        toReturn.add(toAdd);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

This is my method to read input of Laptop objects. The method declaration and parameters must remain unchanged. The output I'm getting for this, however, is an array of length 3, not 4, skipping the first parameter (brand). What's going on here?

Comment: Check what scanner.next is doing...if it's assuming whitespace as a delimiter then it's reading "brand, " as a token and therefore you've moved past that point already by the time you enter your while loop body and read the rest of the line

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code snippet is skipping the first token (brand) is you are explicitly consuming it via `scanner.next()` call in the while loop condition. Since you have not specified any delimiter for the scanner, the first call `scanner.next()` scans the line up to the very first whitespace, removes *brand* and compares it with *"done"*. (As a side note, remember to always compare strings via `equals()` method.)

Since I don't know the format of your file and the reason why you are comparing with *"done"*, All I can suggest is that you check the line only after `line.split(", ")` call.